# Ionic click event fires twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

Lets assume I have an anchor tag. The click event fetches some data from my backend, and the data updates my model.

```
<a ng-if="model.isAuthenticated" ng-click="model.download()" class=button button-small icon ion-android-download></a>
```

Can someone please explain to me why, if I place this anchor inside ion-nav-buttons tags, the click event fires twice ???

```
 <ion-nav-buttons side="right"><a ng-if="model.isAuthenticated" ng-click="model.download()" class=button button-small icon ion-android-download></a></ion-nav-buttons>
```

Comment: This might be irrelevant but do you have ng-controller declared in the html? How about in app.js? How about both? I had an experience not too long ago where I used $state's and I had my controller declared in both, causing it to fire twice.

Comment: Any update with this?

Answer (score 2):

So, turns out there is a bug in ionic that they have no interest in fixing. Essentially, when you use ion-nav-button, additional html is created by the framework. In this case, the framework creates a certain div twice.

When I inspect element, this is what I get:

[image: ionic_bug]

The red crosses indicated that the same div is created twice. One div is active and the other cached. If you are like me, and you have a custom directive inside ion-nav-button, the logic inside your directive will run twice.

For more please read this
[ionic duplicating html elements](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/about-ionic-duplicating-some-html-elements/16917)